# What is a solution develop correctly this Spring and JPA webapp example?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

I have a Controller for my webapp developed with Spring mvc under Maven 3. In this controller I've `@Autowired
      PersonDAO dbController`
I want to use JPA 2.0 to manage persistance so I rewrited my applicationContext.xml:
 I added

```
`<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

  <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<!--    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.tirasa.test.addressbook.dao" />-->
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <!--<property name="generateDdl" value="true" />-->
        <!--<property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />-->
        <!--<property name="database" value="H2" />-->
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>`
```

and my PersonDAOImpl is:

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOJpaImpl implements PersonDAO {

    //@Value("#{entityManager}")
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    //@Autowired
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOJpaImpl.class);

    @Transactional
    public void save(String id, String name, String email, String telephone) throws DatabaseException {

        Person person = null;
        if (find(id) == null) {
            entityManager.persist(person);
        } else {

            entityManager.merge(person);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public Person find(String requestParam_id) throws DatabaseException {
        return entityManager.find(Person.class, requestParam_id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Person> list() throws DatabaseException {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Persons p");
        List<Person> resultList = query.getResultList();
        Person p = null;
        entityManager.find(Person.class, "Andrea Patricelli");
        System.out.println("ECCO UN ELEMENTO DELLA LISTA: ------->" + resultList.iterator().next().getName());
        System.out.println("ECCO IL RISULTATO DELLA FIND: -------->" + p.getName());
        return resultList;
    }
```

but nothing works;
what do I do wrong?
In particular I don't know how to connect My PersonDAO dbController with PersonDAOImpl and with entityManager

Comment: Nothing works is too generic. Maybe you need to reinstall your OS. Take a few minutes or hours to read the Spring documentation on how everything is connected.

Comment: I know, but it's too wide... But I don't have time, I've a milestone to respect and I'm afraid to lose a lot of time on unuseful things only to understand few important things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off your packages to scan is not setup correctly for the entityManagerFactory.  You are scanning your dao's there when you should be scanning your model/domain(Classes with @Entity on them).